# Unable to access to mounted shared drive

Tags: 18.04, mount, nautilus, samba, cifs

Previously, I was able to mount shared drive using the following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=username,pass=passwd,dom=domain //location_shared_drive/ ~/Destination/
```

Now, while I am able to successfully mount the drives, I am unable to access the contents of the directory. SMB mount using the nautilus in-built GUI is able to mount the drive perfectly well with accessbility.

Is there something wrong that I am doing?

Ubuntu version -- 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: I do not have a way to access the host computer. And I checked, the command is still the same.

Comment: but the host computer is likely what changed, this complicates things.

Comment: how do I understand what host computer is sending back as credentials? Is there a way to figure out the response from the host?